# Rerun function from object propery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Hello I come from a very strong OO background and I am trying to apply my knowledge to javascript which many see it as an OO language.

So what I am trying to do is to create an object with some static property values and some others that will change dynamically when the user changes the value of the select box. That works fine but ONLY ONCE, and I have no idea why. After the first time they change the value of the select box I get

> swapDetails.newDriver1 is not a function

Here is my code for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var swapDetails = {
        oldDriver1:"<?php echo $swapDetails[2];?>",
        oldDriver2:"<?php echo $swapDetails[3];?>",
        missionRef:"<?php echo $swapDetails[1];?>",
        date:"<?php echo $swapDetails[0];?>",
        newDriver1:function(){
             this.newDriver1 = $('#swapDriver1').val();
        },
        newDriver2:function(){
             this.newDriver2 = $('#swapDriver2').val();
        }
    };
    $('#makeDriverSwap').click(function(){
        console.log(swapDetails);
    });

    $('#swapDriver1').change(function(){ swapDetails.newDriver1();});
    $('#swapDriver2').change(function(){ swapDetails.newDriver2();});
});
```

Comment: Try `newDriver1:function(){ return $('#swapDriver1').val();
        },`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what logic you want to achieve, but try `return` instead of `this.newDriverN =`

Comment: If i do that then it does not assign the value to the property, instead when you console.log(swapDetails) you see newDriver1:(),.....

Comment: I have an object created as soon as the document is created. The 2 properties newDriver1 and newDriver2 values must be changed dynamically

Comment: You should have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008397/javascript-iife-as-an-objects-property-method

Comment: The way it is now, `this` refers to the `swapDetails` object so when you call `newDriver1()`, `this.newDriver1 = $('#swapDriver1').val();` overwrites itself and is no longer a function.

Comment: Well in java and C++ that would be the way to do it to enforce low coupling high cohension, but its a bit confusing with javascript getting my head around getters and setters. I guess making a setter method would save my problem instead of trying to change the instance of the object's propery value?

Comment: You could make getters and setters, or: instead of calling a function, just set the property from the event handler. Javascript allows you to add/remove properties as needed, as everything is a hashtable. Further, there are no private properties in objects. While JS is OO, it is not class-based; it is prototype based. Alternatively, you can remove the change handlers and just use the functions to return the current value of the option menu as suggested above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your commnets they have directed me to the right direction, indeed the problem here is that I am coding in javascript as if it is a class based. So my solution is to make setter methods. Here is the updated code for anyone who cares in the future:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var swapDetails = {
        oldDriver1:"<?php echo $swapDetails[2];?>",
        oldDriver2:"<?php echo $swapDetails[3];?>",
        missionRef:"<?php echo $swapDetails[1];?>",
        date:"<?php echo $swapDetails[0];?>",
        newDriver1:"",
        newDriver2:"",
        //make object setter methods
        set newDriver1(driver){
            this.newDriver1 = driver;
        },
        set newDriver2(driver){
            this.newDriver2 = driver;
        }
    };
    $('#makeDriverSwap').click(function(){
        console.log(swapDetails);
    });

    $('#swapDriver1').change(function(){ swapDetails.mewDriver1 = $(this).val()}); //call setter method});
    $('#swapDriver2').change(function(){ swapDetails.mewDriver2 = $(this).val()}); //call setter method});
});
```

Thank you once again for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

```
newDriver1:function(){
         this.newDriver1 = $('#swapDriver1').val();
    },
```

The problem seems to be that the you define, with the code above, newDriver1 as a function. Inside that function, you are overriding the newDriver1 function to be a string value. So, the next time this code gets called:

```
    $('#swapDriver1').change(function(){ swapDetails.newDriver1();});
```

The `swapDetails.newDriver1();` has a value, and is not a function as it has been overriden by the value of the input field.
I recommend introducing a different field to store the input value.